# Named (bind) DNS resolver forwarding client subnet

Tags: dns, bind, amazon-ecs, named

Using bind (9.11) i can do a dig with client subnet and make my DNS resolver choose A record based on client subnet (ecs), but i want to put a recursive DNS in between the authoritative server and client , where the Recursive DNS should forward the client subnet to the Authoritative server and receive relevant A record.

dig @ sample.com +subnet=10.0.0.0.24

Where the recursive-dns should forward this request to the Authoritative server along with client subnet.

Is there a way to configure my recursive dns to do that.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Passing ECS (EDNS Client Subnet) is currently only available on the 'Subscriber Edition' of BIND.

BIND does have support for using ECS as an Authoritative nameserver. But not for passing the option through the resolver.

See here for reference :
https://www.isc.org/docs/BIND-9-S-Edition.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented, but only in the bundle PowerDNS Recursor + PowerDNS Authoritative.
"View" bind9 can be replaced with a similar "LUA view" function in PowerDNS Authoritative.